# Why directives selector is in `[]`

Tags: angular

I noticed that a Directive's selector is usually specified in `[]` but is used without the `[]` brackets. Why?

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appGoWild]'
})
export class GoWildDirective implements OnInit {
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'wild');
  }
}
```

Usage in HTML

```
<h1 appGoWild>
  Hello World!
</h1>
```

Comment: if you are enclosing them with square brackets, it will work as attribute selectors and they are as per the style-guide [**#02-08**](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-02-08)

Comment: @Aravind: What makes you think so? That section of the styleguide does not mention square brackets a single time.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper the style guide says us to use attributes for `directives`

Comment: @Aravind: No, it does not. It indicates a naming restriction *in case* one uses attributes (or anything else that is not an element) for directives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives):

> It's the brackets (`[]`) that make it an attribute selector.

So, with brackets, the selector refers to an attribute and has to be written as you state:

```
<h1 appGoWild>
```

Without brackets, the selector would refer to an element:

```
<appGoWild>
```

In the aforementioned docs, you can find an example of that with the `app-root` directive at the end of the article.

Comment: This is the correct answer: because the syntax the Angular team chose says so.

Answer (score 3):

Hope you get a understanding from others answers,
now am explaining a little about selector to get a clear view in this.

There are three types of selector

1. element selector - you can create new html tag
2. class selector - you can use this as class in HTML tags
3. property selector - you can create new property in HTML

   ```
   selector : 'your-option'    // element selector
   selector : '[your-option]'  // property selector
   selector : '.your-option'   // class selector
   ```

To use this in HTML

```
<your-option></your-option>      /* this is element selector usage
<div your-option></div>          /* this is property selector usage
<div class="your-option"></div>  /* this is class selector usage
```

Comment: *property selector* - it's attribute selector. The fact that it also serves to bind properties in template is coincidental; there are not so many balanced delimiters on the keyboard.

Comment: yes, when it comes to directives, we call it as attribute selector

Comment: In addition to @estus comment here is an example where we can see that even `(output)` will be matched like `[output]` https://ng-run.com/edit/GGiJyuOVxqcvAfX1bW8G So `(output)` is just attribute https://alexzuza.github.io/enjoy-ng-parser/#htmlNode

Answer (score 0):

The `[]` in the selector means that the selector name passed will be a property of a tag, not a tag in itself.

Without `[]`, selector will be used as:

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'appGoWild'
})

<appGoWild></appGoWild>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically CSS selector against attribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

These square brackets are different things.

`[]` in selector corresponds to CSS attribute selector. Most directives in use are attribute directives (known since AngularJS), so attribute selectors occur often.

`[]` in template is [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-). If a directive has corresponding `@Input` property, both `<h1 appGoWild>` and `<h1 [appGoWild]>` will work. Otherwise `<h1 appGoWild>` should be used, because `<h1 [appGoWild]>` will cause compiler error.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your example. If the `Directive` say `[appGoWild]` has `@Input` say `@Input() someInput:string` then shouldn't the usage be `<h1 appGoWild [someInput]="Hello">`. When would I do `h1 [appGoWild]`?

Comment: @ManuChadha `h1 [appGoWild]` doesn't do anything useful and same as `h1 [appGoWild]="undefined"`. I believe it will cause virtually no performance overhead. You can use it if you want to designate in template that this is a directive and not just exotic HTML attribute you're not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

It is a convention to use attribute selector `[]` for directives. As directives usually modifies the behavior of the element it is attached to.

For example: we can have directive `appChangeColor` to change background color on `hover`. This can be applied to any element be it -`<p>` or `<a>`.

```
<p appChangeColor>Some Text</p>
<a appChangeColor>Some Link</a>
```

If we use element selector then it would become impossible to add this behavior to the elements.